# WordPress Custom MD5 slug page not found

Tags: wordpress, md5, custom-post-type

My "werknemers" post type need an MD5 generated slug to make them unique. In order to do that, I have added the following code:

```
function isValidMd5($md5 =''){
    return preg_match('/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/', $md5);
}

function custom_unique_post_slug( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type ) {
    if(isValidMd5($slug)) { } else {
        if ( 'werknemers' == $post_type ) {
            $slug = md5( time() );
        }
    }
    return $slug;

}
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'custom_unique_post_slug', 10, 4 );
```

Works perfectly however, the posts are now not accessible, giving a "Page not found" error. Changing the permalinks doesn't help and neither did resetting ".htaccess". I assume I need something specific to be placed in ".htaccess", but I don't know what. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Because I removed the post type slug, the post couldn't be found. 
It actually had nothing to do with the MD5 generator.

To fix it, I had to apply the following code (in case anyone else has this problem)

```
function na_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'werknemers' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'na_remove_slug', 10, 3 );

function na_parse_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'werknemers', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'na_parse_request' );
```